# Javascript Selenium save screenshot in a different directory

Tags: javascript, selenium, screenshot

Is there a way to store a saved screenshot in a specific directory rather than the default root folder? Thanks

Comment: Could you clarify a few things... what have you tried so far/what is your current method to save a screenshot (i.e. are you using `takeScreenshot()`?), what version of selenium are you using, etc...

Comment: my current method is: driver.takeScreenshot().then(function(data) {
       fs.writeFileSync('Customer_Card.png', data, 'base64')
     })" || my selenium version is selenium-webdriver": "^4.0.0-beta.2"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the location to save a file within `fs.writeFileSync()`.

For example, what you are currently doing is equivalent to:

```
driver.takeScreenshot().then(function(data) {
    fs.writeFileSync('./Customer_Card.png', data, 'base64')
})
```

If you want to save your file somewhere else you simply have to include the path.

### Saving into a sub-directory

```
const path = require('path');

driver.takeScreenshot().then(function(data) {
    fs.writeFileSync(path.joing(__dirname, 'innerDir', 'Customer_Card.png'), data, 'base64')
})
```

The above code would save your file to `Customer_Card.png` inside of the `innderDir` directory (which would be at the same place as the file where this code is).

So say for example I have the following project structure:

```
+ MyProjectDir
+---+ savePhoto.js
+---+ innerDir
```

After running the above code I would have:

```
+ MyProjectDir
+---+ savePhoto.js
+---+ innerDir
+---+---+Customer_Card.png
```

`__dirname` is an environment variable that tells you the absolute path of the directory containing the currently executing file.

Alternatively, you can use a relative path like this to get the same effect:

```
driver.takeScreenshot().then(function(data) {
    fs.writeFileSync('./innerDir/Customer_Card.png', data, 'base64')
})
```

### Saving in a parent directory

Finally, if you want to go up a directory instead of into a directory you can do so like this:

```
driver.takeScreenshot().then(function(data) {
    fs.writeFileSync('../Customer_Card.png', data, 'base64')
})
```

Again to clarify,
If this was your project structure:

```
+ MyProjectDir
+---+ innerDir
+---+---+ savePhoto.js
```

Then running the above code (that is in savePhoto.js) would yield:

```
+ MyProjectDir
+---+ Customer_Card.png
+---+ innerDir
+---+---+ savePhoto.js
```

This can be extended so that you can save your file at `./innerDir/innerDir2/Customer_Card.png` or `../../../Customer_Card.png` or even `../../innerDir/Customer_Card.png`.